# Register user cognito in django

Tags: django, amazon-cognito

I am applying cognito into django and try to write a registered user api I used warrant library and are faulty.

```
boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='ap-southeast-2')
user_cognito = Cognito('your-user-pool-id','your-client-id')
user_cognito.register(user['username'], user['password'])
print(user_cognito)
```

my error is:

```
NotAuthorizedException at /api/register_user
An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the SignUp operation: Unable to verify secret hash for client 'your-client-id'
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create an app without client secret.**

It seems that currently, AWS Cognito doesn't handle client secret as it should. In your user pool try to create a new app without generating a client secret. Then use that app to signup a new user or to confirm registration. It worked for me.

Comment: are u using warrant?

Comment: No, boto3, but this is a service known issue. (likely warrant is using boto3 behinds)